# convert html to pdf with several fonts

Tags: c#, itext

i am using iTextSharp 5.5.7.0 
I need to convert an HTML file to a PDF maintaining his style:
As you can see the HTMLi have 2 TD with different font style

```html
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>              
</head>

<body>
    <table>     
        <tr>
            <td  style='text-align:right;font-family:Courier New'>MCV</td>
            <td>102,2</td>
            <td>fl</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='text-align:right;font-family:Courier New'>MCH</td>
            <td>33,8</td>
            <td>pg</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MCHC</td>
            <td>33,1</td>
            <td>g/dl</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EOS2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>10l</td>
            <td>0-0.78</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

i tried with

```
  string fileHTML = @"F:\TemplateVL.htm";
        string HTML = File.ReadAllText(fileHTML);
        FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
        StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
        css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.FACE, "Courier New");

        byte[] bPDF = null;
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 8);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(HTML);
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);


        PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
        htmlWorker.SetStyleSheet(css);

        doc.Open();
        htmlWorker.StartDocument();
        htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);
        htmlWorker.EndDocument();
        htmlWorker.Close();
        doc.Close();
        bPDF = ms.ToArray();

        File.WriteAllBytes("F:\\file.pdf", bPDF);
```

the result is a PDF with a single font for the document
what can i do to maintain the original format?